# API is redirected to an xml page, how do I get the contents of that xml page by calling that api?

Tags: php, xml, api, redirect

First sorry for my grammar, my english is not good.

I'm building a website basically just use the api of a company. Normally when I call the api it returns json array and I can use PHP function "file_get_contents()" and "json_decode()" to process and show the contents of returned data on my website.

But one of their api redirect me to an xml page instead of returning json data. The content of that xml page shows like this:

```
<products>
  <item id="0">
    <product_id>abcdefg12345</product_id>
    <product_name>blablablabla</product_name>
  </item>
  <item id="1">
    <product_id>sdfhtdngfnhf</product_id>
    <product_name>blablablabla</product_name>
  </item>
 .....................................
</products>
```

I was trying to use "simplexml_load_file()" but I dont know how to get the file name of that xml page.

So how could I get the content of that xml page by calling the api redirect me to it using PHP?

Comment: You can retrieve the xml ussing curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `file_get_contents()` and use `simplexml_load_string()` instead. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

Comment: yeah it really works, thanks~~By the way, I have new problem that the xml page function "simplexml_load_string()" loaded is too big(the simplexml object contains thousands of items), is there anyway to just load just part of the xml page?

Comment: What's the problem? Is it taking too long to load? You could always try to substring the loaded string before passing it to simplexml_load_string() but it might not work too well, plus you could end up with unexpected results.

Comment: yes it usually takes around 1 minute to load. So are you saying using "file_get_contents()" to load the whole page is my only choice?